# How to get data from firestore DB in outside of onSnapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Result undefined when I try to get value from firestore and put to a variable, but works in console.

My code:

```
this.db.collection('Users').doc(uid).get()
  .then((docSnapshot) => {
    if (docSnapshot.exists) {
      this.db.collection('Users').doc(uid)
        .onSnapshot((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.data()); //working
          perfil = doc.data(); //not working
        });
    }
  });

console.log(perfil); //not working. Display undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is loaded from Cloud Firestore asynchronously. Because this may take some time, the code after the callback immediately continues. Then when the data is available, Firestore calls your `onSnapshot` callback.

It's easiest to see what's happening by adding a few log statements:

```
console.log('Before adding listener');
this.db.collection('Users').doc(uid).get()
.then((docSnapshot) =>{
  console.log('Got data');
});
console.log('After adding listener');
```

When you run this code, it prints:

> Before adding listener
>
> After adding listener
>
> Got data

This is probably not the order you expected. But it explains perfectly why your `console.log(perfil)` prints `undefined`: the data hasn't been loaded yet!

Because of this, all code that needs access to the data needs to be inside the `onSnapshot` callback. For example:

```
this.db.collection('Users').doc(uid).get()
.then((docSnapshot) =>{
  if (docSnapshot.exists) {
    this.db.collection('Users').doc(uid)
    .onSnapshot((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.data());
        perfil = doc.data();
        console.log(perfil);
    });
  }
});
```

For more on this, see:

- [get asynchronous value from firebase firestore reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51069796/get-asynchronous-value-from-firebase-firestore-reference)
- [Why are the Firebase API asynchronous?](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93)
- [How to get a single document data in a Firebase Firestore (without promises)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47521329/how-to-get-a-single-document-data-in-a-firebase-firestore-without-promises/47523952#47523952)