# How do I obtain the data returned by a Cloud Firestore query?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have written the following code to render some posts (which are stored in a Cloud Firestore instance). I am using mithril.js.

```js
let SummaryPostView = {
  posts: [],
  view: function () {
    let query = blogModels.postModel.getNLatest(20, "created");
    query.then(function (data) {
      this.posts = data;
      console.log("INSIDE VALUE: ");
      console.log(this.posts);
    });
    console.log("OUTSIDE VALUE: ");
    console.log(this.posts);
  }
};
```

When I run my code, I obtain the following console output:
[image: Console output]

The value of `this.posts` is different outside the function to the value of `this.posts inside the function.` As the behaviour of `this` can be confusing I have also tried the following code:

```js
let SummaryPostView = {
  posts: [],
  view: function () {
    let query = blogModels.postModel.getNLatest(20, "created");
    var x = [];
    query.then(function (data) {
      x = data;
      console.log("INSIDE VALUE: ");
      console.log(x);
    });
    console.log("OUTSIDE VALUE: ");
    console.log(x);
  }
};
```

The result of this code is the same:
[image]

In response to Chris Sandvik's answer I have also tried the following code

```js
let SummaryPostView = {
  posts: [],
  view: function () {
    let query = blogModels.postModel.getNLatest(20, "created");
    query.then(function (data) {
      this.posts = data.docs.map(function (doc) {
        let out = doc.data();
        out.id = doc.id;
        return out;
      });
      console.log("INSIDE");
      console.log(this.posts)
    });
    console.log("OUTSIDE");
    console.log(this.posts);
  }
};
```

This still results in the same problem:
[image]

Comment: All code that needs access to the data, must be inside the callback or be called from there. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52488087/how-to-get-data-from-firestore-db-in-outside-of-onsnapshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your output is a QuerySnapshot, you need to access your data like so:

```js
query.then(function (data) {
  this.posts = data.docs.map(doc => {
    let out = doc.data();
    out.id = doc.id;
    return out;
  });
});
```

You need to access the array of documents in your QuerySnapshot using the docs property and the access their data with the `.data()` method.

More info here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.html

Comment: This still results in the same problem, unfortunately.