# Array of JSON object is not empty but cannot iterate with foreach, show zero length

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I read a collection about book `checkout` from firestore in `create()`.

The data is store in `checkout` array that declared in `data()`.

```
export default {
  name: "checkout-history",
  data() {
    return {
      checkout: []
      ]
    };
  },
  created() {
    db.collection("checkout")
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
          querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            const data = {
              id: doc.id, // firebase document id
              book_did: doc.data().book_did,
              borrowed_date: doc.data().borrowed_date,
              copies_did: doc.data().copies_did,
              due_date: doc.data().due_date
            };
            this.checkout.push(data); // push to array
          });
        });

      console.log(this.checkout)  // show data, as in the image below

      console.log(this.checkout.length)  // get 0
      console.log(Object.keys(this.checkout).length)  // get 0
      }
      ......
```

When I run `console.log(this.checkout);`, console show this:

[image]

However, I cannot iterate it, the console show `this.checkout.length` is `0`

I also tried to use Object.keys but no luck.

```
Object.keys(this.checkout).forEach(key => {
     const keys = this.checkout[key];
     console.log(keys);
});
```

I really don't know what to do anymore.

I read many answers online and tried most of them, but none of them work.

Comment: Try `Array.from(this.checkout).forEach(...);`

Comment: Please update your question to show how `this.checkout` is initialized, and how the two snippets relate to each other. As Mamun answered, you're likely logging the length before the data has loaded, but it's impossible to say without seeing how the two snippets relate.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen added in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firestore (and from most modern web APIs) asynchronously. This means that the rest of your code continues to execute after you start the query, and then when the data comes back from the database, your `then()` callback is called. This in turn means that all code that needs access to the data from the database, must be inside the `then()` callback.

```
db.collection("checkout")
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        const data = {
          id: doc.id, // firebase document id
          book_did: doc.data().book_did,
          borrowed_date: doc.data().borrowed_date,
          copies_did: doc.data().copies_did,
          due_date: doc.data().due_date
        };
        this.checkout.push(data); // push to array

        console.log(this.checkout)  // show data, as in the image below

        console.log(this.checkout.length)  // get 0
        console.log(Object.keys(this.checkout).length)  // get 0
      });
    });

  }
  ......
```

Also see:

- [How to get data from firestore DB in outside of onSnapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52488087/how-to-get-data-from-firestore-db-in-outside-of-onsnapshot)
- [Why are Firebase APIs asynchronous?](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93)

Comment: I always forgot async and sync existed. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are executing your code before the completion of the request.

If you hover over the little blue *`i`* icon, it says:

> Value below was evaluated just now.

Comment: Thank you for your time.