# Firebase: Trouble getting field value

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Firestore database]

Given the following data struct in firebase, I wish to retrieve the field in just standard JS. I have tried many methods of getting it, but for some reason, I cannot. I have tried .get(), forEach(), I have tried getting a snapshop, but it won't work.
At the start of my JS file I do:

```
const auth = firebase.auth();
const db = firebase.firestore();

let totalGroups;
db.collection('totalGroups').doc('totalGroups').get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach(function(doc) {
        if (doc.data().totalGroups != null) {
            totalGroups = doc.data().totalGroups console.log("here is total groups" + totalGroups)
            //Total Groups is undefined out here but defined in fuction
        }
    })
})
```

and normally I am able to get .get() just fine. I am looking for the most simple method of getting this value. thanks.

Comment: Can you share the code that you've tried? The `get()` part that you are saying is not working.

Comment: @Dharmaraj
let totalGroups;
 db.collection('totalGroups').doc('totalGroups').get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach(function (doc) {
  if(doc.data().totalGroups != null){
                   totalGroups = doc.data().totalGroups
                   console.log("here is total groups" + totalGroups)

                 }

}

//Total Groups is undefined out here but defined in fuction

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using `get()` on a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) which returns a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) containing data of that single document only and has no `docs` property on it. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
db.collection('totalGroups').doc('totalGroups').get().then(function(snapshot) {
    const docData = snapshot.data();
    console.log(docData)
})
```

Also do note that if you were using `get()` on a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference), then it would have returned a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) where the existing code works fine.

Comment: Thank for for the helpful info, but I still get undefined when I console.log outside the function

Comment: @sdfasdf that is the intended behavior. Read more about this here: [How to get data from Firestore DB in outside of onSnapshot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52488087/how-to-get-data-from-firestore-db-in-outside-of-onsnapshot)